# Uso de REPLACE para modificar el código de una primary key

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando modificar el nombre de una primary key usando el replace, pero no lo consigo. Los códigos de la primary key empiezan por "E" y quiero cambiarlos a "ED".

Por lo que he visto en mysqltutorial debería de ser así, pero no me funciona:

```
update editoriales
set codigo = replace(codigo,'E','ED');
```

Gracias y un salduo

Comment: Ese código es FK en otra tabla?

Comment: Si, es FK en otra tabla, tiene tanto en update como el delete cascade

Comment: Saludos. Si aún no está en uso no debes tener problema alguno; si está en uso es ahí donde seguro recibes algun error; para mantener la integridad de datos deberas buscar donde esta en uso, preparar los UPDATES necesarios para efectar todas las tablas donde esta en uso (como FK) y junto con ella la tabla donde esta como PK; ello en un script que momentaneamente deshabilte dicha comprobación y la vuelva a activar.

Comment: Me salta este error 21:32:44 Data too long for column 'codigo' at row 1
Es una base de datos muy sencilla, todavía estoy practicando :D

Comment: No será que pusiste algo como varchar(10) y tu código es de 10, y ahora al sumar un carácter te queda en 11 ?

Comment: Eso fue lo que me pasó, que tenía un char(4) y tuve que cambiarlo a un varchar(10) Grcias Yussef :)

Comment: Es una buena practica que realices UPDATE y DELETE siempre con un WHERE. Quizás solo quieres modificar un registro en especifico y no la tabla completa. Saludos.